# Auto upload pictures from DSLR to Node.js web app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, camera

I have a web app in Node.js and Angular. In our company we need to take pictures of some products.

In an ideal situation, we would take the pictures with the app open (in a browser on a desktop) and it will automagically upload the pictures to the app.

I know it sounds very easy and I'm pretty sure it won't be. But is there a way to do this? Can it be done via WiFi or only USB?

We are using a DSLR. Right now is Canon (I know they have an SDK) but it would be great to not depend on the camera model or brand.

Thanks!

Comment: You can mount the dslr disk on your system using usb, then watch over folder for changes. This is assuming you are taking about nodejs desktop app and not a webapp

Comment: Okay just saw the webapp in title, not possible directly i guess. maybe write a small node server to run on localhost. Funny thing about webapp is that you can always make calls to localhost, no matter what the host is. Make request to local node server app and add events on that